# Using LIKE wildcards inside pg_prepare

Tags: php, string, postgresql-8.4

I have been trying to use LIKE inside a prepared statement, but php won't execute the statement because of a syntax error due to the use of the wildcard %.

Here is the code

```
$query = pg_prepare($conn, "MyStatement", 
    'SELECT "Query" from "MyTable" 
     WHERE "Query" LIKE $1% 
     ORDER BY "MyColumn" DESC;');

$result = pg_execute($conn, "MyStatement", array($my_param));
```

The thing is that php shows me a warning in the second line claiming a syntax error.

Comment: Not very familiar with postgresql, but my guess is that you need to pass the % in the actual value, not on the binding.   Like array($my_param . '%').

Comment: Thanks Corbin, indeed the solution was the one you provided :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've had the same issue binding parameters using PDO adapters. The solution is to pass the "%" in with the variable:

```
$query = pg_prepare($conn, "MyStatement", 
'SELECT "Query" from "MyTable" 
 WHERE "Query" LIKE $1 
 ORDER BY "MyColumn" DESC;');

$result = pg_execute($conn, "MyStatement", array($my_param."%"));
```

If you need

```
...LIKE '%param%' ...
```

Then your query would be:

```
$result = pg_execute($conn, "MyStatement", array("%".$my_param."%"));
```

Comment: Right.  The syntax error is from quoting. it turns into `LIKE 'whatever'%` instead of `LIKE 'whatever%'`.  So yeah, put the wild cards in the parameter, not the template.